# marrangeGrob but can't add legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I used marrangeGrob() instead of facet_wrap() to produce my plots from a list of plots. However, I can't seem to add a legend.

I already extracted my legend using

```
    g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
      tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
      leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
      legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
      return(legend)}
```

However, I am unable to add it it my plot. 
Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Well, we need to see what code you're running, preferably with sample data that allows us to recreate your plots and legend, to see what's going wrong. If you have, say, two plots, `p1` and `p2` and you heve the legend in an object called `leg`, then, for example, `marrangeGrob(p1, p2, leg, widths=c(5,5,1))` should work.

Comment: hmmm it more like I have a grob named        leg and         plot1<-marrangeGrob(list_of_plots,ncol=4,nrow=5). I want to add legend onto the pdf I produce from this

Comment: The `g_legend` function returns a grob of the legend. You need to include this grob in the call to `marrangeGrob`. If you provide a reproducible example, I can provide code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the built-in `diamonds` data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}
```

First we'll create two plots to lay out together:

```
df <- count(diamonds, cut)

p1 = ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=n, label=format(n, big.mark=","), fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y=0.5*n), colour="white") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

p2 = ggplot(diamonds %>% sample_n(1000), aes(x=carat, y=price, colour=cut)) +
  geom_point()
```

Now save the legend from `p1` as a separate grob:

```
leg = g_legend(p1)
```

Lay out the two plots side-by-side using `arrangeGrob` and then use `marrangeGrob` to lay out the two-plot layout and the legend beneath it. Note that we also remove the legends from the original plots.

```
marrangeGrob(grobs=list(
  arrangeGrob(grobs=lapply(list(p1,p2), function(p) {
    p + guides(colour=FALSE, fill=FALSE)
  }), ncol=2),
  leg), ncol=1, nrow=2, heights=c(20,1))
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, instead of having p1 and p2, my dataframes were orginally in a list. list_df = [df1],[df2],.... I used lapply(list_df,ggplot) to create a list of ggplots. Would your solution still work with this?

Comment: My solution uses a list of ggplots (`list(p1, p2)`). In your case, the list is `plot_list = lapply(list_df, ggplot)` or whatever you do to create your list of plots.

Comment: I see I got it working but I am also looking to create the plots on multiple pages (I have 40 and want to make 2 pages of 20). Is there a way I can implement that onto arrangeGrob()

Comment: also I tried to make the legend on the side by doing ncol=2 nrow=1 height=c(20) but the legend takes up half the page. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: For the second question, allocate less space to the legend by using `widths=c(10,1)` when you lay out the two plots and legend side-by-side.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out!